# Array operations using multiple indices of same array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am very new to Python, and I am trying to get used to performing Python's array operations rather than looping through arrays. Below is an example of the kind of looping operation I am doing, but am unable to work out a suitable pure array operation that does not rely on loops:

```
import numpy as np

def f(arg1, arg2):
  # an arbitrary function


def myFunction(a1DNumpyArray):
  A = a1DNumpyArray      

  # Create a square array with each dimension the size of the argument array.
  B = np.zeros((A.size, A.size))

  # Function f is a function of two elements of the 1D array. For each 
  # element, i, I want to perform the function on it and every element 
  # before it, and store the result in the square array, multiplied by 
  # the difference between the ith and (i-1)th element.
  for i in range(A.size):
    B[i,:i] = f(A[i], A[:i])*(A[i]-A[i-1])

  # Sum through j and return full sums as 1D array.
  return np.sum(B, axis=0)
```

In short, I am integrating a function which takes two elements of the same array as arguments, returning an array of results of the integral.

Is there a more compact way to do this, without using loops?

Comment: It's relatively easy to read now. Any reason you want to compromise that?

Comment: I have been told by a veteran Pythoneer "Do not use loops to manipulate arrays, use array operations." Obviously if this excessively compromises legibility, I'll stick with the loops.

Comment: I'd say a better rule is "do not use loops to manipulate arrays, if an array operation exists that does what you need".

Comment: Thank you @Kevin. My gut tells me that by reducing it to one loop, this is compact enough.

Comment: Just to point out, your mentor is probably trying to point you towards [the vectorize method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) which is described as a function which is *provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.* So the for loop is likely fine

Comment: `"I have been told by a veteran Pythoneer "Do not use loops to manipulate arrays, use array operations." "` - I would think that's meant mostly because working in a vectorized way brings in performance. And if you are going for performance, it would help to know the implementation of func `f`. If you just want compact code, I think you already have a good version.

Comment: To give a little more detail, I suspect your veteran gave you that advice because numpy's built-in array operations are probably implemented in C, and are therefore likely to be much faster than writing out the equivalent code in Python. Incidentally the advice is somewhat less applicable for ordinary Python lists, which aren't quite as performance-oriented as np arrays.

Comment: numpy isn't so good for this kind of thing, and there is an overhead converting between numpy and normal python in your loop. As you are starting with a 1D array you might find that a list comprehension is faster

Comment: Also, why not return np.sum(B, axis=0)

Comment: Thank you @paddyg. Edited my code to match your correction. As I said, I'm very new to python!

Answer (score 0):

The use of an arbitrary `f` function, and this `[i, :i]` business complicates by passing a loop.

Most of the fast compiled `numpy` operations work on the whole array, or whole rows and/or columns, and effectively do so in parallel.  Loops that are inherently sequential (value from one loop depends on the previous) don't fit well.  And different size lists or arrays in each loop are also a good indicator that 'vectorizing' will be difficult.

```
for i in range(A.size):
    B[i,:i] = f(A[i], A[:i])*(A[i]-A[i-1])
```

With a sample `A` and known `f` (as simple as `arg1*arg2`), I'd generate a `B` array, and look for patterns that treat `B` as a whole.  At first glance it looks like your `B` is a lower triangle.  There are functions to help index those.  But that final sum might change the picture.

Sometimes I tackle these problems with a bottom up approach, trying to remove inner loops first.  But in this case, I think some sort of big-picture approach is needed.